# How to get date difference linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I was trying to filter birthdays which comes within the next 14 days. No error was shown even on built. All data are presented to the **result**. But during run time it throws "InValidOperationException"(CS0119).

```
        if (filterModel.IsNextBirthday.HasValue)
        {
            var filteredResult = result.Where(x => x.People.SelectMany(s => s.Details).Any(m => 
                                 ((m.BirthDate).Subtract(DateTime.Today)).Days < 14));
        }
```

Comment: So no error and all data are present. Soooo what's the problem ?

Comment: How does the data looks like ? and what is the expected response ?

Comment: is there any data in the database..also, you can put debugger to see if var filteredResult does get execute.

Comment: But during the run time it throws "InValidOperationException"(CS0119) @Franck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can be done using Linq.

However, I can tell you why it fails.

Think about this part `((m.BirthDate).Subtract(DateTime.Today)).Days`.

`BirthDate - DateTime.Today` will always be negative (unless they are born today, then it will be 0), so it's always going to be less than 14 days.  That's why all data is present in the result - your query matches everyone, even those born today.

If you swap so its `DateTime.Today.Subtract(m.Birthdate)` then the number of days will be much larger than 14 (unless the person is born within the last 14 days).

One method would be to remove the years from the calculation.  As I say, I don't know whether this can be done with Linq, but the logic would be something like below:

```
var birthdateThisYear = m.BirthDate.AddYears(DateTime.Today.Year - m.BirthDate.Year);
var daysUntilBirthday = (birthdateThisYear - DateTime.Today).Days
if (daysUntilBirthday < 14 && daysUntilBirthday >= 0)
{
    // birthday is within 14 days and birthday has not been this year
}
```

If you are using `Linq` you might need to materialise the collection before you can use .NET types and methods (such as `TimeSpan`).

Maybe this will work for you (materialise collection calling `ToList` first):

```
result.ToList()
      .Where(x => x.People
      .SelectMany(s => s.Details)
      .Any(m => (m.BirthDate.AddYears(DateTime.Today.Year - m.BirthDate.Year).Subtract(DateTime.Today)).Days < 14));
```

You also need to check that it's not negative, which would represent a birthday that has already passed this year.

Comment: I already did a method to not show passed birthdays. So "**result**" is a list of upcoming birthdays

Comment: Have you tried calling `ToList` on `result` before using the DateTime filtering? @AjithShan

Comment: Is the problem solved @AjithShan or are there still issues?

Comment: I still have problem

Answer (score 0):

try altering birthdate and datetime.today

```
if (filterModel.IsNextBirthday.HasValue)
    {
        var filteredResult = result.Where(x => x.People.SelectMany(s => s.Details).Any(m => 
                             ((DateTime.Today).Subtract(m.BirthDate)).Days < 14));
    }
```

Comment: Tried! no luck. Actually it only throws CS0119

Comment: @AjithShan, can you please add you class model to your post